# FB api - Error when posting picture on page wall

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create a post on a page wall with the FB api. Like this:

```
FB.api(currentpage.id+'/feed','post',{
  access_token:page_access_token,
  scheduled_publish_time:eventstart.valueOf()/1000,
  published:false,
  link:eventlink,
  picture:'http://addsocial.net'+eventimg,
  message: eventtitle,
}, function(rsp) {
});
```

Everything works fine, if i'm not adding any picture parameter to the post. I get a post-id in return and all is good. But as soon as I add my picture (e.g: http://addsocial.net/mba/media/events/383419425113154/3-buu.png), it gives me the following error:

error: Object
code: 1
message: "(#1) An unknown error occurred"
type: "OAuthException"
**proto**: Object
**proto**: Object

I know its not the URL, because if I remove http://addsocial.net it gives the error: picture URL is not properly formatted. But with this error message, I cant derive anything from it.

Anybody experienced this before, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Try it with an `https://www.` facebook can be a pain sometimes.

Comment: Same error :/ What about the format/size of the image. Does it have to be any specific size?

Comment: try a smaller image size? FB may not like 1.1MB?

Comment: I have tried that too :/